# Find a min value between two dates using different dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

`(Not duplicate)`

I have a `2` `dataframe`

```
# df1 - minute based dataset

date                  value
2018-01-01 00:00:00   1.0516 
2018-01-01 00:01:00   1.0516 
2018-01-01 00:02:00   1.0516 
2018-01-01 00:03:00   1.0516 
2018-01-01 00:04:00   1.0516 
....

# df2 - daily based dataset

date_from             date_to
2018-01-01            2018-01-01 02:21:00
2018-01-02            2018-01-02 01:43:00
2018-01-03            2018-01-03 00:33:00
2018-01-04            2018-01-04 03:11:00
2018-01-05            2018-01-05 00:19:00
....
```

What I want to do is for each `date_from` and `date_to` in `df2` search `df1` which is a minute-based dataframe, find the `min` value between those two dates `date_from` and `date_to`, then put the `min` value in a new column in `df2`.

Our **new** `df2` will look like this:

```
# df2 - with min_value and min_time added

date_from             date_to                 min_value    min_time
2018-01-01            2018-01-01 02:21:00     1.0124       2018-01-01 01:04:00
2018-01-02            2018-01-02 01:43:00     1.1121       2018-01-02 02:01:00
2018-01-03            2018-01-03 00:33:00     1.0126       2018-01-03 01:04:00
2018-01-04            2018-01-04 03:11:00     1.2027       2018-01-04 02:03:00
2018-01-05            2018-01-05 00:19:00     1.0022       2018-01-05 02:21:00
....
```

**What did I do?**

```
df2['min_value'] = 
df1[df1['date'].dt.hour.between(df2['date_from'], df2['date_to'])].min()
```

however, it does not work.

Could you help solve this step by step so that I can understand properly?

Comment: are ranges in df2 overlaping or strictly exclusive?

Comment: the `df2` is a `daily` data with no overlapping `date` and it is `sorted`. Each `row` of `date` is a single day.